# Prevent custom class from being altered by a category

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

Let's assume we have a custom lib with a class that inherits from `UILabel`:

```
//MyLibCustomLabel.h
@interface MyLibCustomLabel : UILabel
```

`MyLibCustomLabel` is linked to a UILabel in a `.xib` file, and text is filled in .xib.

This custom lib is integrated in a project that has a `Category` on `UILabel` class, which has a method to modify `UIlabel`'s text

```
//UILabel+UILabelAdditions.h
@interface UILabel (UILabelAdditions)


//UILabel+UILabelAdditions.m
@implementation UILabel (UILabelAdditions)

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    [self prependText];
}

-(void)prependText {
    NSString *newText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"blabla + %@", self.text];
    self.text = newText;
}
```

In the end, there is a modification non-desired in `MyLibCustomLabel`.

In a situation of both custom class and category are used in a Class, is there a way to protect `MyLibCustomLabel` from any Category on UILabel ?

So that `MyLibCustomLabel` can not be altered in an undesired way, and so that there is no modification to do in the project that integrates it.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that can be done to "protect" a class from a possible category being defined.

But please note that the example `UILabel` category you show isn't valid. A category must never attempt to override an existing method nor attempt to call a `super` method. Such behavior isn't defined and isn't guaranteed to work as hoped.

In other words, the category's `awakeFromNib` method is a bad idea and shouldn't be done. Such a thing should only be attempted in a base class, not a category.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made this example based on something I've seen. On my side I'm trying to "protect" `MyLibCustomLabel`. You kind of confirm my fear that is it impossible. I'll leave the question opened a bit more to gather other opinions, but you are on your way to get the valid answer. Thanks again

Comment: Think of it this way. A category is only supposed to be used to add new methods to an existing class that you don't have access to. A category should never be used to change the behavior of a class. But if a developer writes a category the wrong way and it ends up causing a problem with a class in your library, then the developer writing the bad category is at fault and they will suffer the consequences. I wouldn't worry about it at all.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I was trying everything possible on my side first... Do you know if there is some kind of official guidelines from Apple showing what you are saying? So that I can send it to the one concerned... ^^"

Comment: See the [Customizing Existing Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW1) section of the [Programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210) document.